# Google embed API. can I pass latitude and longitude, at the same time to show a text representation of the address inside the generated popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-embed

I am using Google maps embed api to locate our office , the iframe for showing the map is where I am passing the latitude and longitude coordinates:-

```
<div class="map">

  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=****&q=*1.967842,*5.897120&zoom=18&maptype=satellite"></iframe>                   


</div>
```

This is working well, but the only problem I am facing is that inside the left side popup it will show the latitude and longitude for the location as provided inside the API call which is not very user friendly, as follow:-

[image]

So can i show a string representing the address instead of the latitude and longitude coordinates, but keep passing the latitude and magnitude inside my API call? If this is not possible then can I hide the latitude and longitude?

Comment: can you pass the address in your querystring instead of the lat/lng coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Google](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/YTW6zpVIIkQ) itself it's not possible.

Having said that, what you can do is style your Google map [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/YTW6zpVIIkQ), click on "Generate Code" and embed the javascript in the `<body>` of your website.